Van won’t start no clicking
My van won’t start no clicking radio and dash board lights come on. What could be wrong?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the starter? Have you jiggled the ignition switch? What have you tried to do to figure it out?

It’s likely your starter since there is no cranking noise but dashboard lights illuminate.
Other items to check include the starter, battery, and alternator.

And ignition switch. And neutral safety switch. And brake switch or clutch switch if so equipped. And starter relay if external. Or immobilizer. The point is, DO NOT start replacing parts until further diagnosis has shown what's good and what's bad. The point is, "no click = replace starter" is a strategy suitable only for dishonest mechanics who make a living replacing parts for gullible customers instead of diagnosing the issue.

Thats a valid point raised
